# Virtual environment - how to import in imported local module?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have files (in virtual environment folder with Python34) like this:

```
myfolder/
    __init__.py
    other_file.py
test.py
```

If I call `test.py`, it imports `myfolder` and the `__init__.py` import functions from`other_file.py` with

```
from other_file import a, b, c
```

This throws error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'other_file'
```

Scripts without import of local files work with this virtual env. It also works with Pyton27 without virtual env.

What I am doing wrong? Is it problem of virtual env? Does it allow to import from local modules (not installed)? Or is it difference between Python27 and Python34?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from myFolder.other_file import a, b, c
```

Comment: Ok, it works. But why? With Python 2.7 out of venv it was not required.

Comment: No idea unfortunately!

Comment: Well, ok. Thanks anyway.